# How to sort definition list (DL) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, definition

I have a simple definition list in HTML and I need it sorted alphabetically based on DT value.

```
<dl>
    <dt>fruit</dt>
    <dd>apple, orange, bannana</dd>
    <dt>vegetable</dt>
    <dd>tomato, lettuce</dd>
<dl>
```

Comment: Did you tried anything if at all?

Comment: see this https://api.jquery.com/toArray/

Comment: The only solution I was able to come up with was to put `dd`'s inside `dt`'s, sort `dt`'s, and then put them back out.

Comment: @Ahmedskaya Are you aware of the fact you need to keep `dt`'s and `dd`' consistent, i.e. next to each other?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually we apply sorting on elements that are belonging to particular category.

In your case under `<dl>`, you can apply sorting to either `<dt>` or `<dd>` dom elements.

For such sorting you may use **tinysort jquery plugin**, refer [**to link**](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)

You may refer to [**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/W7bNK/) for sorting  in descending order.

Note: You can change the order.

Comment: Considering the very core nature of Definition/Description List, I naturally need to work with pairs of `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements. Sorting either `<dd>` or `<dt>` dom elements separately is not good enough.

Comment: That's fine. You may refer to tinysort plugin, that can be really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional plugins or libraries it can be simply achieved by putting `<dd>`'s inside `<dt>`'s, sorting `<dt>`'s and then putting `<dd>`'s back out.

```
var dl = $("#my-list");
$(dl).children('dt').each(function() {
    $(this).append($(this).next());
});
var sortedItems = $(dl).children('dt').sort();
$.each(sortedItems, function(i, dt) {
    $(dl).append(dt);
    $(dt).children('dd').each(function(j, dd) {
        $(dl).append($(dd));
    });
});
```

Solution offered by @Mazzu is probably cleaner and better. Thx.